# KIVY : Animating a Label with clock

Tags: python, kivy

Dears,

I'm trying to do a very simple program in Kivy, which will move a Label randomly all over the screen (like the old screensavers).

Would like to use Clock and Random

What am I doing wrong ?

Thks

Code

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from random import random

Builder.load_string('''
<TransLabel>:
    Label :
        text: "test"
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
''')
class TransLabel(Label):
    velocity = ListProperty([10,15])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TransLabel,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60.)

    def update(self,*args):
        self.x += self.velocity[0]
        self.y += self.velocity[1]

        if self.x <0 or (self.x + self.width) > Window.width:
            self.velocity[0] *= -1

        if self.y <0 or (self.y + self.height) > Window.height:
            self.velocity[1] *= -1

runTouchApp(TransLabel())
```

Comment: I think the main problem is that you have defined a `TransLabel` class that extends `Label`, but your kv language creates another `Label` inside that class. Try removing the `Label:` line from your kv and unindent the three lines after that.

Answer (score 0):

The label that contains the text should not have the size of the root, since when executing the `update()` method the text will be oscillating since the sentences that evaluate the if will always be true.

You must also compare the position of the text with respect to the window, not the position of the root with the window since they have the same size.

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from random import randint

Builder.load_string('''
<TransLabel>:
    Label :
        id: label
        text: "test"
''')

class TransLabel(Label):
    velocity = ListProperty([10,15])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TransLabel,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1./60)
        self.x = randint(0, self.width)
        self.y = randint(0, self.height)

    def update(self,*args):
        self.x += self.velocity[0]
        self.y += self.velocity[1]

        label = self.ids.label

        if self.x <0 or (self.x + label.width) > Window.width:
            self.velocity[0] *= -1

        if self.y <0 or (self.y + label.height) > Window.height:
            self.velocity[1] *= -1 

        label.pos = [self.x, self.y]

runTouchApp(TransLabel())
```